# Deploy Laravel .env file based on environment

Tags: laravel, continuous-delivery

I am creating a CI/CD pipeline for my Laravel application but I kinda don't understand .env environment file. In Laravel [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/configuration#environment-configuration) it is stated that:

> To make this a cinch, Laravel utilizes the DotEnv PHP library. In a
> fresh Laravel **installation**, the root directory of your application
> will contain a .env.example file that defines many common environment
> variables. During the Laravel **installation** (**what is this installation process here?**) process, this file will
> automatically be copied to .env.

> Your .env file should not be committed to your application's source
> control, since each developer/server using your application, could
> require a different environment configuration

- Where to store this `.env`, for different environments if not in the source repo, and make it automatically copied to prod env?
- Is there any command to create `.env` file based on provided params that this command can be executed as a part of production deployment and .env file be generated automatically?
- Do I need to manually copy/paste the production .env file or create some custom Bash script, is there any Laravel/artisan specific way to do this?
- What does the documentation mean by example env file will be copied during installation process to env, is there any other process different than the initial one?

Answer (score 1):

It's very big decision, depends to your infrastructure and deploy process. Secrets management is not easy. I can show you one way, answered to your questions.

### Where to store this .env

1. Create folder `deployment` in your project. In this folder create folder `environments` and subfolders `dev`, `stage`, `prod`, etc
2. Create `.env` files with your variables in this folders
3. Use [sops](https://github.com/mozilla/sops) to encrypt this files
4. Push this files to repo
5. On deployment process, decrypt file, referring to deploy environment.

### Is there any command to create .env

If you have params in array - just make this - variables will be read from env vars

```
foreach ($params as $key => $value){
    putenv("$key=$value");
}
```

### Do I need to manually copy/paste the production .env

Not, you don't

### What does the documentation mean by example env file will be copied during installation process to env

It's mean - example env will be copied at first install, look at composer.json:
"post-root-package-install": [
"php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');""
],

Comment: I use archive winrar with password.